# iPhone UIPickerView and array

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I'm looking for best way to populate UIPickerView with data from webservice. I have web service:
Country1`Country1CODE`
Country2`Country2CODE`
Country3`Country3CODE`

I made all parsing correct and i can reach all values of service like service.country or service.code.

Problem is what  in UIPickerView I need to show list countries, but return as value selected country code. (i hope i explained understandable). All day i was looking for best way how to do it, but I didn't found nothing... Thanks for you help and wasted time :)

Answer (score 1):

Once you've retrieved the data from the web server, your best bet is to use an [NSDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as a repository for the data, which you'd use to store the country codes as objects with the country name as the key.

i.e.: ... dictionaryWithObject:@"826" forKey:@"United Kingdom"

You could then use the NSDictionary allKeys method to obtain an NSArray of country names to populate the UIPickerView with and (once the user has selected a country) can trivially retrieve the corresponding country code via the NSDictionary objectForKey method.